# Getting the dimensions of a sibling widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add two widgets to a screen as in the picture below:

[image]

"Widget A" is a container of an unknown size as it varies depending on the amount of text in it.
"Widget B" should always overlap "Widget A" and be placed partially below it and at only 75% of the width of widget A.

I know I'll most likely need a Stack for the widgets to be drawn on top of each other.

I've used layout builder before to get constraints of a parent, but in this situation "Widget A" and "Widget B" are both siblings of the stack, so I'm not sure how to get its size.

Comment: send your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after scratching my head for a while, just after posting I worked out how to do it.
So "Widget A" is in a column, with some space at the bottom and widget B is positioned in the stack at the bottom

```
Stack(
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children: <Widget>[
    //widget a
    LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight-10,
            child: widget.child,
            color: Colors.indigo,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
        ],

      );
    }),
    //widget b
    LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      return Container(
        height: constraints.maxHeight,
        width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.75,
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
      );
    }),
  ],
);
```

Comment: use expanded widget

Comment: @MuratAslan not sure how that would help given the need for the widgets to overlap

Comment: wrap your layoutbuilders with expanded then see the result